# duplicate the object and then update a value in JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a array of json objects in jquery . I want to duplicate a object and then replace  key value in original object on the basis of if condition . but every time i replaced the value in single object then it replaced the values in both objects . I only want to replace in one i.e original 
I have used break and return false statements but dont work.

```
var index=getIndex(class_id,teacher_id);

    finalJson[index]['teacher_name']='asad';

function getIndex(class_id,teacher_id){
    for(var it in finalJson){
    if(finalJson[it]['class'] == class_id && finalJson[it]['type'] == 'c'){
        finalJson.push(finalJson[it])
        return it;
        }
    }
}
```

please anybody help here is if condition .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related question: [What is the most efficient way to clone an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: Using jQuery you can clone object using `$.extend({}, finalJson[it]);`

Comment: can you post `finalJson`? in the question too.

Comment: solved with deep copy .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `finalJson.push(finalJson[it])` you are pushing the reference to old object again in the array. So, any operation done on one reference will be performed on the object to which new reference is pointing to. Which is why you need to create a new object using the properties of old one (using `Object.create`) and then push it.

replace

```
finalJson.push(finalJson[it])
```

with (don't use this option)

<strike>finalJson.push(Object.create(finalJson[it]))</strike>

or a slower but deep-copy option

```
finalJson.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(finalJson[it])));
```

Comment: `Object.create(finalJson[it])` will not clone the object only create new object with prototype of old object, so each time old object change new object will change too.

Comment: @jcubic I know that it will not do deep cloning but in this case deep cloning isn't required as it seems OP's json isn't of multi level. I have given another option anyways.

Comment: `Object.create(finalJson[it])` is simply wrong becuase it will work like cloning a reference or assign object to different variable `a = finalJson[it]` if you change `a` it will change `finalJson[it]` too. The same happen with prototype. it's not cloning at all.

Comment: @jcubic as per the spec https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create new object is created with the same properties.

Comment: New object is created but the prototype is taken from old object so if you change old object new object will be modified. take a look that this https://jsfiddle.net/smfs8f58/

Comment: @jcubic okay, got it. Updating my answer to remove the first option. Second one should still work though. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy the object to a new variable, you are creating a reference. You need to create a new object to prevent this, otherwise the changes applied to one object will apply to the other.